Google Sheets Conditional formatting issue using ifna()
I have a Google Sheet that has 2 columns in it.  The first column, Column A, is a list of ticket numbers.  The second column, Column D, is a list of winning ticket numbers.  I would like the list of ticket numbers to have the cell highlighted if it is in the list of winning tickets.
For example, Column A has the row values of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.  Column D has the row values of 3 and 7.  So I'd like to use conditional formatting on column A to change the background color of the cells with 3 and 7 to yellow.
I've set up a condition formatting rule as follows: Range is A1:A10, Format Rules (Format cells if...) is "Custom formula is", and the formula I entered is "ifna(match(Address(Row(),COLUMN()), D1:D10), 0) = 0".  Under Formatting Style, I've currently set it as the default green background with black letters, but I have tried it with the background fill set to yellow.  Clicking the Done button does not produce any error messages.
(Note that I set the formula to be "= 0" so that all but the two matches should have their background fill changed.  I'll change that to "> 0" in the final version.)
My issue is that none of the backgrounds are changed by the conditional formatting.  Anyone have an idea or two of things I can try to get this to work?  Or anyone have a different was of having this same idea work using a different method?
As a side note, the final version of this sheet will have over 3000 tickets and 90 winning tickets.  I am not concerned with using volatile or nonvolatile functions.  Either is fine with me.  Speed is not something I am concerned with as this sheet is just used by me.  I just want something that works.  :-)


Here's one approach you may test out:
=xmatch(A1,D:D)



This is what I'm looking for, sort of.  :-)  It works perfectly if the tickets are all in one column.  But the final sheet I'm actually working with has the tickets spread out across several columns.  Is there a modification to make this work across multiple columns or should I just make a conditional format for each column?

try =xmatch(A1,tocol(D:F,1)) (assuming 3 columns here D,E,F)

I don't think this will work  The winning tickets are all in column D while the tickets I need to search are in columns A, B, and C.  So I need any tickets in columns A, B, or C that are also in column D to have their background changed.  So in the above example,  Column D has 3 and 7,  tickets 1 - 5 are in column A and tickets 6 - 10 are in column B, and column C has tickets 11 - 15.  So I would need A3 and B2 to have their backgrounds changed.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Here's the link to a sample with the "Tickets Sold" that are in the "Winning Tickets" having their background color manually set to yellow:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oWmfFfPCulES-mpxT8zUgbQB3hxpnVciigUgrecKAFI/edit?usp=sharing
Ticket Range is A2:T202 and the winning ticket numbers are in range W2:W69.  Note that the winning tickets are not normally sorted.  I did this so I could find and change the backgrounds of the tickets easily.  Also note that there is an empty row between the 112xxx through 113xxx tickets and the 727xxx through 728xxx tickets.  Thanks for helping.

Apply to range : A:T formula: =xmatch(A1,$W:$W)

One last question, if the winning numbers were on a sheet called "Winning Numbers", can I modify the formula to be =xmatch(A1,'Winning Numbers'!$W:$W)?  I tried this and it told me the formula had an error in it.

=xmatch(A1,indirect("Winning Numbers!$W:$W"))

an alternative:
=MATCH(A1,D:D,)


